# Why isn't this.parent() defined as a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9TcpB/)

I'm creating a new button element with

```
$('<button>Remove Entry</button>', { 'type': 'button', 'class': 'delete_button' });
```

However the neither the `type` or `class` attributes seem to be defined, and the console prints an error saying `this.parent()` is not a function (though I'm positive I enabled jquery)

I'm afraid I've done something simple and stupid, but I can't seem to find anything wrong.

Comment: How about `$(this).parent()`

Comment: Or `this.parentNode` (the DOM version)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason that the attributes are not set on the element, is that you are mixing different uses of the jQuery method.

To use the method in a way that it uses an object for attributes, the first parameter should be a single tag, not a HTML snippet:

```
$('<button>', { 'type': 'button', 'class': 'delete_button' }).text('Remove Entry');
```

The reason that `this` doesn't have a `parent` method is that it refers to an element, not a jQuery object. You would use `$(this)` to make a jQuery object from the element reference.

Also, `this` referers to the new entry button, not the remove entry button, as you are calling the method when you are binding the event. You should call the method when the event happens:

```
delete_button.click(function() {
  remove_entry($(this).parent())
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9TcpB/1/

```js
  var entries = 0;
  
  function new_entry() {
    entries++
    new_entry_div = $('<div>', { 'class': 'entry' }).appendTo('form');
    new_entry_div.html('<p><input type="text"></p>')

     
//     delete button
    delete_button = $('<button>', { 'type': 'button', 'class': 'delete_button' }).text('Remove Entry');
    delete_button.appendTo(new_entry_div);
      delete_button.click(function(){
          remove_entry($(this).parent());
      });
  }
  
  function remove_entry(entry) {
    entry.remove();
  }
  
  $("#newButton").click(function () {
    new_entry();
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input">
      <form>
      </form>
      <button id="newButton">New Entry</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You're basically doing this

```
$("#newButton").click(function() {
    new_entry;
});

function new_entry() {
    this.parent();
}
```

but inside the callback for the event handler, `this` is native JS DOM element, not a jQuery object, so it has no jQuery methods, you have to wrap it first, as in

```
$("#newButton").click(new_entry);

function new_entry() {
    $(this).parent();
}
```

Comment: Well if "new_entry" is being called from the handler, it'd also be necessary to arrange for `this` to be passed along too.

Answer (score 4):

`this` contains a DOM element. If you want to use jQuery methods, you have to convert it to a jQuery object with `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/n2vd8/)***

Retain the current context using the `call` method:

```
$("#newButton").click(function () {
  new_entry.call($(this));//now this in new_entry refers to `$(this)`
})
```